# What is the difference in meanings of these two sentences?

Tags: sentence-meaning

*I have heard the poem being recited on numerous occasions.*

*I have heard the poem recited on numerous occasions.*

How is the first sentence different from the second sentence?

Answer (score 0):

In most contexts they would mean the same thing. However if a person worked in a building where elocution lessons were given they might hear fragments of the poem being recited without ever hearing the entire poem. In this case your first sentence would be better.